# Hyper-V Live Migration Fails

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, live-migration

I have a failover cluster consisting of two nodes: VS1 and VS2.  Each node is running Windows Server 2008 Datacenter R2 SP1.  They have slightly different processors (E5335 and E5420), so I'm running my test VM in [Processor Compatibility mode](http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2009/05/12/tech-ed-windows-server-2008-r2-hyper-v-news.aspx).  The [Virtual Machine Migration Test Wizard](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VMMTestWizard/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3326) confirmed that this would be necessary.

I cannot successfully do a Live Migration.  Here are the cluster logs from the failure.

```
00000b6c.00001494::2011/08/29-21:14:39.895 INFO  [RES] Virtual Machine <Virtual Machine IT2>: State change 'Online' -> 'MigrationSourceSetup'
00001158.000014e8::2011/08/29-21:14:39.926 WARN  [RCM] ResourceControl(UNKNOWN (0x160000c) obj: .MU. flags:2097164 code:0 access:<<insert {4} refers an argument that is not supplied. Only 4 argument(s) provided>>) to Virtual Machine IT2 returned 1168.
00000b6c.00001494::2011/08/29-21:14:39.926 ERR   [RES] Virtual Machine <Virtual Machine IT2>: 'Virtual Machine IT2' live migration did not succeed at the source.
00000b6c.00001494::2011/08/29-21:14:39.957 INFO  [RES] Virtual Machine <Virtual Machine IT2>: State change 'MigrationSourceSetup' -> 'MigrationSourceCanceled'
00000b6c.00001760::2011/08/29-21:14:39.973 INFO  [RES] Virtual Machine <Virtual Machine IT2>: Current state 'MigrationSourceCanceled', event 'MigrationSourceOfflineResult', result 0x80004005
00000b6c.00001760::2011/08/29-21:14:39.973 INFO  [RES] Virtual Machine <Virtual Machine IT2>: State change 'MigrationSourceCanceled' -> 'Online'
```

The only other bit of info I have to offer up is the following error from the System event log.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-High-Availability
Date:          8/29/2011 4:37:33 PM
Event ID:      21502
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      VS1.domain.local
Description:
'Virtual Machine IT2' live migration did not succeed at the destination.

Configuration setup for live migration failed on the destination node. Make sure that name of the virtual network is the same on the source and destination nodes, and try the live migration again.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-High-Availability" Guid="{64E92ABC-910C-4770-BD9C-C3C54699B8F9}" />
    <EventID>21502</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x2000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-08-29T21:37:33.981393600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2987</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="5276" ThreadID="5480" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>VS1.domain.local</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ResourceName">Virtual Machine IT2</Data>
    <Data Name="ResourceGroup">'Virtual Machine IT2' live migration did not succeed at the destination.

Configuration setup for live migration failed on the destination node. Make sure that name of the virtual network is the same on the source and destination nodes, and try the live migration again.</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The only other person I could find that was having this issue posted [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/virtualmachinemgrclustering/thread/706792b6-4942-42b8-ba21-a50c27a40d04/).  He never mentioned using compatibility mode, so I'm not willing to accept this as an answer.  As you can see in the image posted on the site from my first link, it's possible to do live migration between some pretty disparate processors.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified network names are the same.  Per the error message: "Make sure that name of the virtual network is the same on the source and destination nodes, and try the live migration again."

Comment: Everything seems really "same-ish" to me, but I'm not positive that I'm looking in the right location.  Is there a simple command I can issue to verify this?   Update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2475761

Comment: There isn't a simple command that I'm aware of.  You'll need to log into each machine and verify that each virtual network is exactly the same (name, subnet, etc...)

Comment: OK, I verified that they are named exactly the same.  I even chose a new name, set them both to it, refreshed the config and it still failed.  I only have one Virtual Network on each of my Hyper-V machines - each External, each connected to 2 adapters teamed together.

Comment: Ok, for troubleshooting purposes at this point I'd try it without the adapters teamed.

Comment: I lose.  Total idiot.  Thought I had two Hyper-V MMC windows open; one showing me VS1 and one showing me VS2.  In reality, I had two Hyper-V MMC windows open offering me two identical views into VS2's settings.  Of course everything matched!  @murisonc - feel free to write up an answer, preface it with "Hey, dummy..." and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my intial comment was correct.

Have you verified network names are the same. Per the error message: "Make sure that name of the virtual network is the same on the source and destination nodes, and try the live migration again